# TelnetLib não fecha corretamente o socket

Tags: python

Estou a desenvolver um script em python que envia sms usando uma ligação telnet a um mv-372 da portech.

O script funciona corretamente mas passado algum tempo a ligação telnet cai e lança uma excepção "[Errno 32] Broken pipe". Como o script está a rodar como um serviço do systemd sempre que encontro um erro termino o script e o systemd reinicia-o.

Quando o script reinicia entra num loop porque não se consegue conectar ao modem por telnet. O script só volta a conectar-se quando faço reboot ao modem.

Aqui fica um exerto do código:

```
# Creare a Telnet Connection to Host1
try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    sleep(1)
    tn.read_until('username: ')
    SendCommandToSocket(USERNAME, "password: ", 10, tn)
    SendCommandToSocket(PASSWORD, "info.\r\n]", 10, tn)
    print "Connection Established"
except Exception as e:
    print e
    logger.critical('Cannot connect to socket. Exception is: %s' %e)
    tn.close()
    sleep(10)
    exit()
```

Antes de tcerminar o script eu fecho sempre a onexao telnet usando tn.close().

Alguém sabe-me dizer porquê a ligação fica bloqueada após o script terminar?

Answer (score 0):

Sabe fazer uma análise de pacotes?
Tenta usar o tcpdump ou wireshark pra fazer uma análise do ponto que acontece e depois está sendo rejeitado.
Está parecendo que seu Script está enviando um pacote e o mesmo está recebendo um reset.
tcpdump -nvtttS iphost 
se quiser salvar acrescenta....
-Z $USER -w save.dump

Com certeza uma análise vai te dar um norte ao que está acontecendo.